# How to Display table data as User Ratings

Tags: asp.net

I want to display user ratings in my asp.net site using bars and ratings. The value is retrieved from data table (it's to be something like YouTube's like / dislike bar )
Can anybody guide me to do it in asp.net web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft recently released a cool new ASP.NET server control -  - that can be used for free with ASP.NET 3.5 to enable rich browser-based charting scenarios: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

[image]